# Pipenv on windows failing with error installing wrapt (python 3.6.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I'm starting on a new python project and when I try to install my virtual environment I keep getting a failure with `wrapt`. I've read and tried all solutions I could find here and other forums for a couple of days but without success.

Could you think of what the problem could be to give it another go? This is pretty strange as the same project and code works in other Windows machines which are similar...

```
D:\git_project>python --version
Python 3.6.8

D:\git_project>pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

D:\git_project>pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2018.11.27.dev0

D:\git_project>python -m pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: D:\git_project\Pipfile
Using C:/Python36/python.exe (3.6.8) to create virtualenv…
[=== ] Creating virtual environment...Already using interpreter C:\Python36\python.exe
Using base prefix 'C:\\Python36'
New python executable in C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\git_project-UBvgpj5x\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:/Python36/python.exe

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\admin\.virtualenvs\git_project-UBvgpj5x
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (1e32a5)…
An error occurred while installing wrapt==1.11.2 --hash=sha256:565a021fd19419476b9362b05eeaa094178de64f8361e44468f9e9d7843901e1! Will try again.
  ================================ 84/84 - 00:02:14
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[InstallError]:   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 251, in install
[InstallError]:       site_packages=state.site_packages
...
...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "c:\users\admin\.virtualenvs\git_project-ubvgpj5x\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         st = os.stat(path)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     ----------------------------------------
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

This is a link to the complete output in case you can find something useful to try and clarify what's happening? 
https://pastebin.com/raw/8gdUUZN8

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed setting the following variable before running: `pipenv --three install`

> set WRAPT_INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=false

Comment: It solved my problem. However, I don't understand what's the impact when setting it to false? It seems that the solution is just making the program "ignore" the error". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same stack trace and my issue was that the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable wasn't installed on my machine. It's a bit silly, but the install script just looks for the dll and breaks with this error if it's not there instead of checking it first and showing a meaningful error message...

The important part of the stack trace:

```
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "c:\users\admin\.virtualenvs\git_project-ubvgpj5x\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "c:\users\admin\.virtualenvs\git_project-ubvgpj5x\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1620, in return_env
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       if self.vs_ver >= 14 and isfile(self.VCRuntimeRedist):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "c:\users\admin\.virtualenvs\git_project-ubvgpj5x\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       st = os.stat(path)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ----------------------------------------
```

`self.VCRuntimeRedist` will return `None` if the C++ Redistributable is not installed, which will lead to this error when `isfile` is called with `None`.