# Python 3.6: tensorflow install on windows failed with TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, typeerror, setup.py

I am new to Python and Tensorflow. I tried to install tensorflow using the command pip install --upgrade tensorflow. However, the installation fails at two points:

1. Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py)
2. Running setup.py install for wrapt

During both these instances, the error is the same

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

Can anybody suggest some solution for this error?

Comment: Seems to be [a popular error recently](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20TypeError%3a%20stat%3a%20path%20should%20be%20string%2c%20bytes%2c%20os.PathLike%20or%20integer%2c%20not%20NoneType), especially with [`wrapt`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59113149/7976758).

Comment: Created a virtual env and then tried pip install tensorflow and it still did not work. Failed to install wrapt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipenv on windows failing with error installing wrapt (python 3.6.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113149/pipenv-on-windows-failing-with-error-installing-wrapt-python-3-6-8)

Answer (score 7):

I had same failure, tried older Python, older TensorFlow but no luck.  Then fell upon this and it works for me (I'm on Windows).  Make sure you do the following:

`set WRAPT_INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=false`

before running having `pip install tensorflow`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`set WRAPT_INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=false`

Worked for me, but I had to run it from a command window, not powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted a lot of time troubleshooting this, but for me the root cause was that `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` wasn't installed. (or the latest version)

The install script built the path of a dll in this package based on where it's *supposed to be* and one util function returns the path *if it exists* and None if it doesn't. The next util function will break with the above mentioned error if the dll doesn't exist and the previous function returned None. (`genericpath.py` and `msvc.py`)

This error seems to be a symptom of another problem, which is the root cause. (missing C++ redistributable in my case). 
If you are feeling adventurous you can take a look at the stack trace and see who is calling the function with None. You might be able to add a few `print`s and see what is the root cause for you.

Answer (score 0):

Took me hours to find this page finally as a solution. I tried everything, reinstall different versions of python, cleaning up my pc, etc. @AdamColton, you're a genius.
Installation worked for me with tensorflow 2.0.0 and python 3.6.8 like a charm with this line of code before.